# How to Prepare data for LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, feature-selection

I'm having difficulties to wrap my head around how I can prepare my dataset to train an LSTM.

Below is a screenshot of a subset representation of my dataset.

[image]

There are several other feature not included in this screenshot. The last column is inhospital_mortality which is 0 or 1 for each row.

Each feature was taken at a certain time x. features with the same feature_1,2,3 were taken at the same time.

My idea is that I will need to break every row (sample) as the example below: So in this case, each row would become 6 new rows.

```
| tc_tb1 | spo2_tb1 | g1_tb1| inhospital_mortality (label 0 | 1) |
| tc_tb2 | spo2_tb2 | g1_tb2| inhospital_mortality (label 0 | 1) |
| tc_tb3 | spo2_tb3 | g1_tb3| inhospital_mortality (label 0 | 1) |
...
| tc_tb6 | spo2_tb6 | g1_tb6| inhospital_mortality (label 0 | 1) |
```

Am I correct here? If so, how could I accomplish this dataframe manipulation in a more straight forward way? Perhaps there's a better way to reshape turn this dataset into the format I want. I wasn't able to accomplish it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.
About your problem, you say that your last column **inhospital_mortality is binary** so your goal is to classify, at a certain time with some info about them, patients likely to die in hospital if I am right.

Assuming this is your goal, I think you can try a **classification approach** without reshaping your dataset to a time series format, since you are **not interested in forecasting** a sequence (or a point in that sequence), you have independent buckets of x measurements per patient, without temporal connection in your training history.
You can use certain lag values (the -1, 2, 3... you already have) as informative features, and proceed with a **binary classifier**. Other option is, with this approach and per patient, calculate some statistical values like min, max, mean... of the 8 measurements for each type of patient indicator, while keeping the same number of rows but aggregating the attributes.

Of course you can also reshape it by having a unique date-time index with a value for each attribute type as you say, but you end up with less input features per row to predict your inhospital_mortality target value.

If you are interested in actually forecasting and eventually use an LSTM as you suggest, you might want to have a look at other answers about this type of problem like [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88494/time-series-multi-step-generalization-from-single-step-model/88664#88664)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, my goal is to classify if a patiend died given certain info. I agree with you that this looks like a traditional classification approach that I could use random forest or an SVM to classify.  However, I've been told to use LSTM for this task to classify and I'm confused on how I can shape my data in a way that would make sense for my LSTM model. I'm not even sure if using LSTM is any useful in this case.

Comment: I have read your response and it's still unclear how I could reshape my data to use in a LSTM.

Comment: First, I would wonder: how many samples do I have? Does it make sense to use a train a recurrent net in you case? Second, if you cannot achieve a good enough performance with the current approach, you must set the date time as index, to have one row per time and rest of values, so it becomes a sequence

Comment: Regardless LSTM is a good approach or not for this problem (which I would say based on this info it is not), you can have a look at the answer I posted on the answer link

Comment: I see. I have about 4.5k samples. So, in my case since I don't have a feature that has a timestamp, would I have to add a new column to input timestamp? Sorry just a bit unclear on this.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have not a single column that indicates a timestamp. The only info I have is that of the _index for each feature that indicates that the measures were taken one after the other.

Comment: So you mean 4.5k rows of the original dataset, meaning 4.5k patients? If that's the case, you have, for each patient, several attributes measured 6 times. Let me know if this is the case

Comment: Yes, here is the output from the shape: (4883, 506). Each row I have is a different patient. The features are several measurements such as heart rate, glucose, creatine, and etc.. each feature has 8 columns in the dataset that were measurements taken.

Comment: One more detail is that I just trained a RandomForestClassifier on the original shape and due to unbalanced nature of my dataset, my classifier only predicts the majority label. Tried a few oversampling/downsampling methods and nothing changed. I wonder if NN would help with that.

Comment: I updated the answer with an additional comment; I suggestbyou to aggregate the 8 measurements buckets per patient, and proceed with the binary classifier. From my experience, I would use the LSTM if I want to forecast with a long sequence as training input, but in your case, you have independent buckets of 8 measurements per patient, without temporal connection in between

Comment: About the imbalance situation, that is another problem, with you can try to work out by downsampling, but is very important the metric you select (area under precision-rfcall for instance) so you judge your model correctly, considering the minority class. Additional hyperparameters like class weight is available with scikit learn decision trees or scale_pos_weight with xgboost

Comment: So, you're saying that the way I had envisioned in my question is the correct way to shape the data? 
Each patient will end up having 8 rows?

Comment: That's what I suggest in my answer, no need to reshape it as a sequence problem, but you can also try to generate those statistical features instead of keeping the 8 measurements per patient

Comment: Maybe I missed your point here. By statistical features, you mean that I should for instance get the 8 columns for heart rate measurements, hr_1, hr_2, ..., hr_8 and condensed them into 1 column by taking the mean (other methods as well)?

Comment: Into 1 or more, as follows (per patient row of course): min, Max, mean, std... of the 8 heart rate measures, the same for 8 blood pressures, etc